# Adding zeros between elements in list?

Tags: list, haskell

I'm trying to change a list in haskell to include 0 between every element. If we have initial list `[1..20]` then i would like to change it to `[1,0,2,0,3..20]`

What i thought about doing is actually using map on every function, extracting element then adding it to list and use `++[0]` to it but not sure if this is the right approach or not. Still learning haskell so might have errors.

My code:

```
x = map classify[1..20] 

classify :: Int -> Int 
addingFunction 0 [Int]


addingFunction :: Int -> [a] -> [a]
addingFunction x xs = [a] ++ x ++ xs
```

Answer (score 12):

[`intersperse`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Data-List.html#v:intersperse) is made for this. Just `import Data.List (intersperse)`, then `intersperse 0 yourList`.

Comment: Yes that works too but kinda wanted to dig deep to Understand Haskell more

Answer (score 8):

You cannot do this with `map`. One of the fundamental properties of `map` is that its output will always have exactly as many items as its input, because each output element corresponds to one input, and vice versa.

There is a related tool with the necessary power, though:

```
concatMap :: (a -> [b]) -> [a] -> [b]
```

This way, each input item can produce zero or more output items. You can use this to build the function you wanted:

```
between :: a -> [a] -> [a]
sep `between` xs = drop 1 . concatMap insert $ xs
  where insert x = [sep, x]

0 `between` [1..10]
[1,0,2,0,3,0,4,0,5,0,6,0,7,0,8,0,9,0,10]
```

Or a more concise definition of `between`:

```
between sep = drop 1 . concatMap ((sep :) . pure)
```

Answer (score 4):

With simple pattern matching it should be:

```
addingFunction n [] = []
addingFunction n [x] = [x]
addingFunction n (x:xs) = x: n : (addingFunction n xs)

addingFunction 0 [1..20]
=> [1,0,2,0,3,0,4,0,5,0,6,0,7,0,8,0,9,0,10,0,11,0,12,0,13,0,14,0,15,0,16,0,17,0,18,0,19,0,20]
```

Answer (score 3):

If you want to use `map` to solve this, you can do something like this:

Have a function that get a int and return 2 element list with int and zero:

```hs
addZero :: List
addZero a = [0, a]
```

Then you can call map with this function:

```hs
x = map addZero [1..20] -- this will return [[0,1], [0, 2] ...]
```

You will notice that it is a nested list. That is just how `map` work. We need a way to combine the inner list together into just one list. This case we use `foldl`

```hs
combineList :: [[Int]] -> [Int]
combineList list = foldl' (++) [] list 
-- [] ++ [0, 1] ++ [0, 2] ...
```

So the way foldl work in this case is that it accepts a combine function, initial value, and the list to combine.

Since we don't need the first 0 we can drop it:

```hs
dropFirst :: [Int] -> [Int]
dropFirst list = case list of
  x:xs -> xs
  [] -> []
```

Final code:

```hs
x = dropFirst $ combineList $ map addZero [1..20]

addZero :: Int -> [Int]
addZero a = [0, a]

combineList :: [[Int]] -> [Int]
combineList list = foldl (++) [] list 

dropFirst :: [Int] -> [Int]
dropFirst list = case list of
  x:xs -> xs
  [] -> []
```

Comment: `foldl (++) []` is a bit weird. Why not just point to `concat`?

Comment: @amalloy Yes it is. It is just that `concat` implementation itself also use some type of `fold`. So I guess using `foldl` would help other understand it a bit deeper.

Comment: `concat` is implemented using `foldr` rather than `foldl`. Do you understand why this is actually important?

Comment: I do not fully understand the subject of `fold`myself. There is a whole wiki related to this subject. My simple understanding is that `foldr` is much better for lazy infinite list, and `foldl` or `foldl'` (strict version) is better for general use-case.

Answer (score 2):

We here can make use of a `foldr` pattern where for each element in the original list, we prepend it with an `0`:

```
addZeros :: Num a => [a] -> [a]
addZeros [] = []
addZeros (x:xs) = x : foldr (((0 :) .) . (:)) [] xs
```

Answer (score 2):

If you don't want to use `intersperse`, you can write your own.

```
intersperse :: a -> [a] -> [a]
intersperse p as = drop 1 [x | a <- as, x <- [p, a]]
```

If you like, you can use `Applicative` operations:

```
import Control.Applicative

intersperse :: a -> [a] -> [a]
intersperse p as = drop 1 $ as <**> [const p, id]
```

This is basically the definition used in `Data.Sequence`.